# cPanel not uploading .htaccess file

Tags: cpanel

cPanel does not appear to be uploading the .htaccess file.
Tried to drag or use the upload option but in vain.
All other files have successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably there but you cannot see it without changing your view settings to reveal hidden files.

[image]